# Spring boot with impala kudu

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, impala, kudu

Hi I am trying to auto generate table on impala kudu using spring boot , but it always show error
"table not exists default.hibernate_sequence"
is there is possible way to create table automatically from entity on impala?